# Firebase: Is there a way to see the JSON payload being sent from the SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've been developing an iOS app using Firebase for a few months, and I've run into an issue where a call to my backend is failing. To test the issue, I open up the simulator on Firebase and simulate the call, and it succeeds with no issues. All other calls work as expected.

**The only conclusion I can come to is that the JSON payload differs, in some way, from what I expect it to be.**

Some details:
The view controller I'm in is doing continuous observing of a data structure on the backend (using *observeEventOfType:withBlock:withCancelBlock:*), and checking boxes on that screen manipulates child values of that same data structure. So each time a box is checked or unchecked, it does a *setValue:* call with the new value. Then, since the parent data structure is being observed, it gets updated, and the screen is refreshed.

The problem I'm having is that the *setValue:* call get rejected, which in turn hits the cancelBlock of the other method. When I try to simulate that *setValue:* on my Firebase dashboard, it succeeds.

I've added the relevant backend rules and the failing method in question in a github gist here:
https://gist.github.com/jakehawken/4a4bb8d2f58c651d7310b3a1737bf11e

```
//RELEVANT BACKEND RULES FOR THE FAILING CALL (I'm writing to the "completed" path):
"subtasks": {
    "$list_item": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['subtaskDescription', 'completed'])",
        "subtaskDescription" : {
            ".validate" : "newData.isString()"
        },
        "completed" : {
            ".validate" : "newData.isNumber() && !newData.hasChildren()"
        }
    }
}
```

METHOD CALL THAT IS FAILING (Objective-C):

```
- (KSPromise *)markSubtask:(HDInProgressSubtask *)subtask completed:(BOOL)completed forListID:(NSString *)listID inProgressItemKey:(NSString *)inProgressKey subtaskKey:(NSString *)subtaskKey
{
  KSDeferred *deferred = [KSDeferred defer];

  FIRDatabaseReference *specificSubtaskReference = [self specificSubtaskCompletionReferenceForListID:listID inProgressItemKey:inProgressKey subtaskKey:subtaskKey];

  FIRDatabaseReference *subtaskCompletionReference = [specificSubtaskReference child:kCompleted];

  NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithBool:completed];

  [subtaskCompletionReference setValue:value withCompletionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error, FIRDatabaseReference * _Nonnull ref) {
    if (error)
    {
      [deferred rejectWithError:error]; //Failing case
    }
    else
    {
      [deferred resolveWithValue:@(completed)]; //Success case
    }
  }];

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

The call should simply be sending up the number 1 or a 0 (a BOOL wrapped in an NSNumber), but when I turn on verbose logging, it says it's sending up this behemoth:

```
{
  "d" :     {
        "a" : "p",
        "b" : {
            "d" : 1,
            "p" : "<the url path for this upload>"
        },
         "r" : 11
    },
    "t" : "d"
}
```

The apparent success from the simulator:
[image: sensitive information redacted]

Comment: Cross-posted: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/XujlZtvDl6c

Comment: I'm not the best at reading obj-c; what is the value of `completed`? Is that writing an integer directly to  the completed field? Are we sure that's being set? Also, where is the .write rule that allows write to this path? Not seeing that here or in the gist.

Comment: It's a Boolean so even if it was never assigned, it would just show up a false value. That literal syntax just wraps that Boolean in an NSNumber. The write rule is higher up in the tree, but calls higher up the rule tree are passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself.

I commented out all of my validation rules so that I could post anything I wanted to the backend. I had figured, up to this point, that since I was wrapping my boolean in an NSNumber, I figured the backend would store that value as a number. Accordingly, my rule for that path was newValue.isNumber(). It turns out, however, that Firebase automagically knows that it’s a boolean, so when I stripped out all my rules, the value that got posted to the backend was “true.” So, I rewrote the rule to be newValue.isBoolean() now it works just fine.

**Moral of the story:** If you initialize an NSNumber with a boolean, then when you hand that off to Firebase, the JSON payload that gets created will be made with the awareness that the NSNumber was a boolean to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Closest you can get is by [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase#setloggingenabled):

```
FIRDatabase.setLoggingEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Then copied that log to the dashboard simulator. The simulated call passed.  :-(

Comment: In order to help with that I'll need to see the [minimal code (+JSON +rules) that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've now included a Github Gist with the relevant code in the question body.